# Find the tags with the most/least answered questions

Tags: support, tags

Is there a way to view this?

I know that by clicking on the tag will show the number of questions that are answered overall, in the last 30 days, and the last 7 days.

Is there a broader list that can be sorted or similar?

Comment: Would this be what you're looking for? http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/68941/unanswered-questions-by-tag - or do you need up-to-date info?

Comment: @Mat, very useful, and what I was looking for, but I was hoping that it would be more built in.

Comment: There’s not much reason to build this sort of functionality into the sites because then there would requests to build in dozens and dozens of such functions. It’s kind of like Chrome; include the necessary stuff and leave the extras for extensions.